# how to model many-to-one relation using ezplatform?

Tags: ezplatform

project has lots of asset, an asset belongs to a group. then we have 3 content types

Project, ProjectAsset, AssetGroup

1. store the assets relation in Project content type.

   Project

   name
   assets relation

   ProjectAsset

   image
   group relation

   Group

   name

with this approach, we need to upload  project asset first, then add this relation to project.

2. Store relation in ProjectAsset itself.

   Project

   name

   ProjectAsset

   image
   group relation
   project simple relation to project.

   Group

   name

with this approach, we specity relations(project, group relation) when we upload project asset.

## what I want to do

1. when delete project, the project asset should be deleted as well. does ezplatform support embed association like doctrine orm?
2. when query project, I also need to get the project assets. what is the efficient way to do this? the `query`  might be for a single project or a lists of project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi "out of the box" it's not possible but of course there is a solution for that. It requires some developpement though
What I would do is add an EventListener (or EventSubscriber) plugged on specific object type deletion so it triggers the appropriate deletions of related objects.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html